# An example of a function and the Fourier transform both vanishing on some sets

Tags: analysis

Can anyone give me an example of a function f $\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and its Fourier transform both vanishing on non empty open sets? I think f itself cannot be compactly supported, because in this case, its Fourier transform is analytic, it cannot have accumulating point. Then I have no idea what to do next. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: if we suppose $f(x)$ is zero on $U = B(0,r)$ the ball at the origin of radius $r$, then $f \ast \frac{\sin(||x||/r^d)}{C||x||}$ cannot be zero on $U$,
because it is analytic so it vanishes only at isolated points ?

Comment: http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM1983v045n03ABEH001014/pdf
This paper may contain the example you would like to have.

Answer (score 0):

It may be harder in the case $d=1$, but it's easy if $d > 1$.  Let's take $d=2$ for simplicity, with $f(x,y) = g(x) \mathscr F^{-1}(g)(y)$ where $g \in \mathbb L^2(\mathbb R)$ vanishing on an interval $J$.  Then $f$ vanishes on $J \times \mathbb R$ while $\mathscr F (f) (p,q) = \mathscr F(g)(p) g(q)$ vanishes on $\mathbb R \times J$.

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thanks! But how can we construct the 1-dim example?